# How to create a custom example environment for r markdown pdf output?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am hoping to create a custom-styled example environment within r markdown that renders pdf output.

I want something that looks like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357520/create-example-frame) or like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21227/example-environment), but I still want the example to be numbered, and I want to use the simple syntax

```
'''{example} <!-- I use ' instead of ` to make it appear in this question -->
Hello  
'''
```

throughout my document. Is this achievable? Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I am adding a minimal example

```
---
header-includes:
   - \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
   - \newtheorem{example}{Example}
urlcolor: blue
extension: latex_macros
numbersections: true
output:
   bookdown::pdf_document2:
      toc: false
biblio-style: apalike
---

'''{example} <!-- I use ' instead of ` to make it appear in this question -->
Hello  
'''
```

Then I get something like this

[image]

But I would want the example to be styled and numbered. Maybe put inside a block that look maybe like this (Image from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357520/create-example-frame), but no example number and I can't just use the r markdown block)

[image]

Comment: you'd probably have to define/load the environment type in the include-header part of the yaml header and then do something like \begin{env}...\end{env}

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] so we can see which output type etc you are using

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I did make a minimal example, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tcolorbox` for the example:

````
---
header-includes: |
   \BeforeBeginEnvironment{document}{
      \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
      \let\example\undefined 
      \let\endexample\undefined 
      \newtcolorbox[auto counter]{example}{
        colback=white,
        colbacktitle=black,
        arc=0mm,
        title={Example~\thetcbcounter:},
        bottom=-.7\baselineskip,
        colframe=black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries
   }}
urlcolor: blue
extension: latex_macros
numbersections: true
output:
   bookdown::pdf_document2:
      toc: false
      keep_tex: true
biblio-style: apalike
---

test

```{example} 
Hello  
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use some packages as for ordinary LaTeX. I give you an example with the packages **thmtools** and **mdframed**.

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: 
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
    keep_tex: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

\begin{example}
    Hello I am an example.
\end{example}
````

File **preamble.tex**:

```
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\definecolor{verylightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\color{black}\normalfont\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\color{black}\normalfont\sffamily,
  mdframed={
    backgroundcolor=verylightgray, 
    hidealllines=true, 
    innertopmargin=2pt, 
    innerbottommargin=2pt, 
    skipabove=\topsep, 
    skipbelow=\topsep
  }]{mystyle} 

\declaretheorem[
  style=mystyle,
  name=Example
]{example}
```

[image]

A linebreak or a top margin is needed...